# Can i use windows phone 8.1 device for development on windows phone sdk 8.0

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have windows mobile phone which is updated to 8.1 recently. I did signup for Microsoft developer account and registered this mobile on windows SDK 8.0  . When I run solution to deploy on this device , I am getting some error messages .

My question is can i use 8.1 phone device n SDK 8.0 solution .

Thank you

Comment: yes what error are you getting?

Comment: Thanks I will post the errormsg  once  i go home and access my dev system.

Answer (score 0):

But i don't think you could develop `WP8.1` apps in `VS2012`. For that you gotta have the 8.1 Development tools.

[Windows Phone 8.1 development tools](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk)

You mean testing WP8 apps in a WP8.1 device? In that case yes you can.

What you can't do is testing WP8.1 apps in a WP8 device.

Comment: Hi , you mean we can not run application from windows 8.1 SDK  on wp8 device ?  . Application made for wp8 and distributed through windows store can be installed on 8.1 device right as it should be backward compatible ..

Comment: It isn't backwards compatible you can run 8.0 apps on 8.1 but not 8.1 apps on 8.0 as @Kulasangar said.

Comment: yes your first question was right. But the latter part cannot be done as @gabriel mentioned.